# Replacing three way switches with insteon

Tags: electrical

Replacing 2 three way switches that control a group of recessed lighting with Smart Insteon switches. As background, Insteon switches require a neutral and don't use travellers since there 3 ways connect wirelessly.

Normally the hot(s) get connected to the Insteon black, and the red (load) get's attached to the light in one box and capped in the other box. And both get attached to ground and neutral. With this set of neutrals it seems a bit different since one of the switches already seems to have a white wire attached and the other switch has a screw that is attached to two wires. Tried attaching based on what made the most sense but neither switched powered on.

Can someone help suggest which current wires match up with the news switches, since what worked for the rest of the house doesn't work for these.

[image: Wiring]

[image: High resolution version as requested]

[image: 3 way Switch under recessed lighting]
[image: 3 way switch across room]

Comment: Wanted to add another note. Unplugged the hot red from both switches and turned on the circuit breaker. The light turns on and I'm still able to control the lights via the switches, however then if i flip one switch to turn off the light, the other switch can't turn it back on, and vice versa.Both of those unplugged red wires are still hot even when unplugged. Also when all the wires are plugged in, if i unplug the black cold wire from the switch in the top right of the above image the light doesnt turn on.Does any of that help?

Comment: Is there another junction box involved in this circuit?  Also, can you get us MUCH larger photos of the junction boxes?

Comment: Also, it really helps to know how the wires are grouped as they exit the junction box.  And what's happening with every wire in any of the groups that go to these switches.   For instance the left switch must have a minimum of 3 wire groups - the power supply, the cable to the lights, and the cable to the other switch.   Of course the power supply will be shared with other switches, we're not worried about that.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Yes this is a three way switch (so two gang boxes), which are shown above via a picture and a diagram. The diagraph below the pictures show the actual wire hookup. Let me know if there is something else you need to know about the junction box not pictured in the diagram and happy to provide!

Comment: @Harper Yes, if you look at the diagram above I note how the wires are bundled. That is for instance the left diagram, there is a note saying that the red and black next to each other are coming from one bundle, and the other red and black come from one bundle. And the diagram on the right has a note mentioning that the red black and black come from the same bundle. Was that what you were looking for?

Comment: The problem is that we need bigger pictures -- not more diagramming -- we can tell things from the pictures that most folks miss.

Comment: @cchiera Yeah, but that only covers 2 bundles and doesn't account for where those neutrals go.   "bundle of neutrals" does not say whether it is those particular white wires.   If you post the additional pictures to Imgur, we can edit them inline into the post.

Comment: @Harper Sure so in regards to neutrals question the gang on the left above, the bundle of neutrals is compromised of one neutral coming from each bundle of wires coming into the gang box. I regards to that only covers 2 bundles, that is correct, the switch is comprosised of only 2 bundles, plus one neutral wire coming from the neutral bundle.

Comment: As to more photos -- we can use photos looking into the backs of the boxes too -- just post them to [imgur](https://imgur.com) and link them here in comments if you can't edit them into the question.

Comment: This simply doesn't make any sense.  There's more to this story.  If those two switches are connected directly to each other (presumably `hot/red` and `cold/black` are messengers) then why is the white wire hot?  Did you actually measure `hot/white` and find 120V relative to ground on it?

Comment: @Harper Yeah confusing to me too, as the wiring for this three way seems different than the others we've updated to insteon in the house. Most notably, it has a hot white wire attached where is none of the other basic switches had a white wire attached. Used a Klein tool to test which are carrying a current and which are not. Will post separate comment with additional image(s).

Comment: @Harper Added photo of both boxes above. The other switches in the boxes are unrelated to this recessed lighting, and will be replacing those after this issue is resolved. The original pics show the old working switches hooked up. The new images show with them unplugged so you can see in more easily and whether hot or not. Let me know if I can provide additional info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular situation will involve rewiring the old dead end 3-way.

The white tied to the blacks needs to be rewired as a neutral.  Currently it is wired as a common (hot).  Then one of the travellers needs to be rewired as a permanent hot.  This will allow your dead end Insteon to be powered up.

The black and red that where tied together is the switch leg.  It ties to the red on the Insteon. The rest should fall into place.

Don't forget to turn off the breaker(s).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So in the top left plug, the previous red/black that were together goes to red on insteon, great. Ground goes to ground. Confused on where to plug in the remaining red and black. In the other box there is a hot white that you mention that needs to be rewired but not sure what you mean by rewiring it. If you could let me know which should attach where like with the red/black, that would be great!

Comment: I created a graphic and labelled each wire 1A, 1B, etc, that was it may make it easier to say which should go to which. Such as 1B should go to 3C and 3D. Not sure about the others. Didn't include grounds in graphic but of course would connect those too. http://i.stack.imgur.com/hIMVX.jpg

Comment: @cchiera  The remaining red black are the travelers.  As mentioned earlier, you will need to send permanent power on one of the travelers to the dead-end Insteon, AND a neutral.  The white tied to the blacks needs to be removed and tied to the other whites so it can be used as a neutral at the dead end Insteon.

Comment: I'm not really interested in the schematic.

Comment: In the 3 gang box the white tied  to blacks are for a different switch in that same gang box, so didn't want to touch any of the wires going to unrelated switches in the same multi gang box. But if your saying that should be done and won't negatively affect those other switches I can try that. Which would involve removing the white tied to the 2 blacks for that other switch, and attaching that white to the other bundle of whites that are used by the new insteon. The schematic was more so would be easier to describe/name exactly which wires should hook up to accomplish what you are suggesting.

Comment: I think if you were to look closer at the white tied to the blacks you would see it comes out of the same 3-wire.  But please verify that with another picture if you don't mind.

Comment: Ok, so in the 3 gang box, 1B now goes to 3C and 3D (aka red insteon to the red/black colds). The white that attached to 2 blacks that powered a separate near by switch, has been moved to 3A (the white bundle). I assume the remaining hot red goes to insteon black, and the remaining cold black gets capped? The in the other gang box, white goes neutral (2A > 4C) and red goes to black insteon (4A > 2C) and black (4B) and insteon red (2b) gets capped? Doing that I get no power to either, so must be missing something.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you other than the the dead end Insteon needs permanent power and a neutral to work.  From your original picture you can put everything back together as it was beforehand, make everything works as before.  Start-over from square one. And again add another picture as I can't see to be 100% that the white tied to the blacks is or is not with the 3wire.

Comment: So in addition to connecting the lines mentioned in my last comment, in the three gang box, instead of attaching the insteon black 1C, to to the red 1B, I attached it to the 2 black wires (that previous had the white wire attached). That gives power to that switch and light. Then attached the red (3b) to the same black bundle (Where use to be white attached), and the other one works. So all working now! Unless you or anyone sees anything incorrect about that hookup. Thank you!